# geopandas overlay() function not working in QGIS

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgis, geopandas

I need to find the intersection of a GeoDataFrame with itself through geopandas in QGIS. The code works perfectly in the Anaconda environment but it fails in the QGIS python.

Shapefile is available at below link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQqg7Cf6AokyadkmOE8Y6k41tqDMXdmS/view?usp=drivesdk

Below is the code:

```
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("C:\\QGIS_ShapeFile1\\qgis\\laneGroup.shp")
intersection_gdf = overlay(df1, df1, how='intersection')
```

In QGIS, the following error occurs:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
         File"C:/Users/sn43673/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ad_qgis\shapefile_validator.py", line 318, in errorInShapeFile
    intersection_gdf = overlay(df1, df2, how='intersection')File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 391, in overlay
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 216, in _overlay_intersection
    for k in j:
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4042, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 216, in 
    for k in j:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a small reproducible code example?

Comment: @joris I have added the shape file in the above description. You can use it with the above code.

Comment: Thanks for that. What version of GeoPandas are you using in both environments? (you can check with `geopandas.__version__`) For me this is working with both geopandas 0.5.1 and 0.6.0

Comment: I am using 0.6.0. Where did you check it, on Anaconda?

Comment: Its working fine with anaconda but it's not working with QGIS

Comment: I only check in Anaconda, not QGIS. You are sure that you are using 0.6.0 in QGIS as well?

Comment: Yes am sure. Mine is also working in anaconda. But I need it in QGIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this error recently. It was due to DLL issue in RTree package.
You should try replacing libspatialindex.dll file.

Comment: Thank You, Faiz. That actually worked. I replaced those dll files from anaconda.